# do_rootfs failed on yocto build

Tags: yocto

I have integrated a makefile based project into custom recipes within yocto but there was an issue: do_rootfs failed.

Please find library source and I try to integrate this library into oe-core: http://libiec61850.com/libiec61850/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/libiec61850-0.9.0.2.tgz

.bb file:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:" FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

DESCRIPTION = "simple Hello World program" PR = "r0" LICENSE = "CLOSED"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

DEPEND = "libpthread-stubs libiec61883 libraw1394" SRC_URI += "    \
        file://config   \
        file://demos    \
        file://dotnet   \
        file://examples \
        file://make     \
        file://Makefile \
        file://src      \
        file://third_party \
        file://tools    \
        "

EXTRA_OEMAKE = "'CC=${CC}' 'RANLIB=${RANLIB}' 'AR=${AR}' 'CFLAGS=${CFLAGS} -I${S}/include -DWITHOUT_XATTR' 'BUILDDIR=${S}'"

do_compile() {
             oe_runmake ${S}/make } do_install () {
        oe_runmake install DESTDIR=${D} SBINDIR=${sbindir} MANDIR=${mandir} \
                           INCLUDEDIR=${includedir}
        install -d ${D}${includedir}/libiec61850/
        install -d ${D}${localedir}
        for f in ${S}/.install/include/*.h; do
                install -m 0644 $f ${D}${includedir}/libiec61850/
        done
        install -m 0644 ${S}/.install/lib/* ${D}${localedir}/ }
```

The error looks like:

```
Configuring volatile-binds.
Configuring libxcb-xkb1.
Configuring libxkbcommon.
Configuring libidn11.
Configuring libattr1.
Configuring libacl1.
Configuring libz1.
Configuring libkmod2.
Configuring udev.
Configuring kmod.
Configuring iptables.
Configuring libcap2.
Configuring liblzma5.
Configuring util-linux-fsck.
Configuring systemd-compat-units.
Configuring systemd-serialgetty.
Configuring angstrom-version.
Configuring udev-hwdb.
Configuring libe2p2.
Configuring libext2fs2.
Configuring e2fsprogs-e2fsck.
Configuring systemd.
Configuring kernel-image-4.1.15-v2.5b3+ge6d111c.
Configuring angstrom-feed-configs.
Configuring netbase.
Configuring packagegroup-core-boot.
Collected errors:
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package libiec61850.

ERROR: Function failed: do_rootfs
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /media/kanji/edb1a7c2-288e-488e-abce-24d478f6cd46/workspace/kanji/oe-core/build/out-glibc/work/colibri_vf-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.8560
ERROR: Task 7 (/media/kanji/edb1a7c2-288e-488e-abce-24d478f6cd46/workspace/kanji/oe-core/build/../stuff/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb, do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1865 tasks of which 1864 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
NOTE: Writing buildhistory
No currently running tasks (1864 of 1866)

Summary: 1 task failed:
/media/kanji/edb1a7c2-288e-488e-abce-24d478f6cd46/workspace/kanji/oe-core/build/../stuff/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb, do_rootfs
Summary: There was 1 WARNING message shown.
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to provide an exact answer here as there's a few things which are likely wrong or at least problematic.  So lets work backwards:

```
Collected errors: * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package libiec61850.
```

This means that when installing the list of packages it could not find a literal libiec61850 file.  I assume that you created libiec61850_0.9.0.2.bb and that is what the bb file contents above represent.  Aside from whitepace problems that I assume are due to copy/paste into here, it looks OK.  But check out the log.do_compile and log.do_install  To make it easier to see if there were any problems building just that package, do:

```
bitbake -c cleansstate libiec61850
bitbake libiec61850
```

and see if it complains about empty packages.

Next, you may be having a problem with recipe name -> binary output renames.  Do:

```
ls tmp/deploy/ipk/*/*iec61850*
```

And see what the results are.  If you would like to examine the contents of a particular ipk file they are just 'ar' archives so you can extract them:

```
mkdir temp
cd temp
ar -x ../foo.ipk
tar zxf data.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thank you Tom :) I have also tried to attach log file but I am unable to search attachment option in post and I had solved this issue yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

I had find the solution of above mention issue :

```
 FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
    FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

    DESCRIPTION = "libiec61850 library support added"
    PR = "r0"
    LICENSE = "CLOSED"

    S = "${WORKDIR}"


    SRC_URI += "    \
        file://config   \
        file://demos    \
        file://dotnet   \
        file://examples \
        file://make \
        file://Makefile \
        file://src  \
        file://third_party \
        file://tools    \
        "

    DEPEND = "libpthread-stubs"
    RDEPENDS_${PN} += " \
            update-alternatives-opkg    \
            opkg-arch-config    \
            run-postinsts   \
            "

    EXTRA_OEMAKE = "'CC=${CC}' 'RANLIB=${RANLIB}' 'AR=${AR}' 'CFLAGS=${CFLAGS} -I${S}/include -DWITHOUT_XATTR' 'BUILDDIR=${S}'"

    do_compile() {
                 oe_runmake ${S}/make
    }

    do_install () {
            oe_runmake install DESTDIR=${D} SBINDIR=${sbindir} MANDIR=${mandir} \
                               INCLUDEDIR=${includedir}
            install -d ${D}${includedir}/libiec61850/
        install -d ${D}${libdir}/
            for f in ${S}/.install/include/*.h; do
                    install -m 0644 $f ${D}${includedir}/libiec61850/
            done
        install -m 0644 ${S}/.install/lib/* ${D}${libdir}/
    }


    FILES_${PN} += "${includedir}/libiec61850/* ${libdir}/*"
    PACKAGES = "${PN}"
```

Comment: could you post the full recipe